# Use SQL To Retrieve Row-wise Data As Columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, sybase

I have a data set in a Sybase database that is modelled by the following [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ffe26/1)

Using the following basic query I can extract the subsequent data:

**Query:**

```
SELECT [Scancode], [Product Name], [Store Name], [Quantity]
FROM Sales
JOIN Items
ON   Items.PK  = Sales.ITM_FK
JOIN Stores
ON   Stores.PK = Sales.STO_FK
```

**Data:**

```
SCANCODE    PRODUCT NAME    STORE NAME  QUANTITY
123456789   Milk            Tokyo       19
123456789   Milk            New York    28
123456789   Milk            London      37
987654321   Eggs            Tokyo       46
987654321   Eggs            New York    55
987654321   Eggs            London      64
192837465   Bread           Tokyo       73
192837465   Bread           New York    82
192837465   Bread           London      91
```

I would like to retrieve the data in an "item centric" format:

```
SCANCODE    PRODUCT NAME    Tokyo Sales  New York Sales  London Sales
123456789   Milk            19           28              37
987654321   Eggs            46           55              64
192837465   Bread           73           82              91
```

***Is there a scalable & efficient way to retrieve data in this format?***

~ Scalable means that more stores can be added without modifying the query.

Comment: Is this for MS SQL or Sybase? They are different.

Comment: If it's for Sybase the PIVOT approach will not work. You should be able to use the approach described here 
[How do I rotate a table? - SQL Anywhere Forum](http://sqlanywhere-forum.sybase.com/questions/275/how-do-i-rotate-a-table). I haven't tried it though as I don't have any Sybase server.

Comment: It is a Sybase database, and that link makes my eyes hurt!

Comment: You have tag `tsql`and your fiddle is mssql.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Sybase isn't an SQLFiddle option... MSSQL seems to be the next closest thing...

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Fiddle doesn't have any option for Sybase, and t-sql is used in both MS and Sybase, but different with extensions (or dialects if you will).

Comment: @awashburn The example in the link I provided should be pretty straighforward to adapt. The only difference is that you have an extra column that you have to handle.

Comment: You want a scalable option that can accomodate additional stores.  That *IS* the format that you don't want to use.  Can you explain why the normalised format is inadequate?  It is the correct structure to use and has been used for many, many years.  It is considered more maintainable, robust, adaptable, scalable and generalised than the one you're asking for.  That implies that your need for the pivotted format is the problem, not the normalised format it self.

Comment: @MatBailie I'm not exactly sure what you mean by 'normailized form'. Also, I have no control over the current DB schema (proprietary), I just know what I need to retrieve data from the schema.

Comment: @awashburn - From wikipedia: `Database normalization is the process of organizing the fields and tables of a relational database to minimize redundancy and dependency.`  In your case it leads to data-sets that are long and narrow, rather than the short and wide data-set that you're asking for.  It's a fundamental aspect of good database design and brings an extra-ordinary number of benefits that at first are not always apparent.  It is a topic you may wish to investigate, but the culmination is that you *should not* change the structure, it's already in the 'right' structure.

Comment: @awashburn - You may indeed need to change the structure at the moment that you present it to the user, but good architecture keeps those two layers of concern separate - Use the DB for storing, processing and providing data (in the normalised form), and *later* in your application manipulate it as required for *presentation*.

Comment: @MatBailie I get everything that you are saying. From what I learned in university's DB class, I agree that the current DB schema is optimal/correct/normalized. However, I would like to retrieve the data for the user from the database in the user's desired format without an application layer between the user & the database. The intended use was to develop an SQL payload for a MS Query shortcut... It is beginning to appear that I may need to insert an application layer for maintainability...

Comment: @awashburn - Yes.  Don't use SQL for application / presentation functionality.  It's not supposed to be there, so there is much less support for it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *[`MatBailie`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53341/matbailie)* pointed out, Sybase's lack of a `PIVOT` function forces you to separate data presentation from data retrieval. Your options are limited to writing an inextensible kludge or restructuring the data in an intermediary application layer.

I opted to sacrificed scalability for the lack of an intermediary application layer.

**My solution follows [this form](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ffe26/5):**

```
SELECT
  [Scancode],
  [Product Name], 
  MAX( CASE WHEN STO_FK = 1 THEN net.Total ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Tokyo Sales',
  MAX( CASE WHEN STO_FK = 2 THEN net.Total ELSE 0 END ) AS 'New York Sales',
  MAX( CASE WHEN STO_FK = 3 THEN net.Total ELSE 0 END ) AS 'London Sales'
FROM Items
JOIN (
  SELECT ITM_FK, STO_FK, SUM([Quantity]) AS Total
  FROM Sales
  JOIN Stores
  ON   Stores.PK = Sales.STO_FK
  GROUP BY ITM_FK, STO_FK
) AS net
ON Items.PK = net.ITM_FK
GROUP BY
  [Scancode], 
  [Product Name]
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can do that using a dynamic SQL. You need to first build a list of stores which you'll be able to use in the pivot query dynamically.

Note: I replaced your source data with `src` table for simplicity.

```
    declare @stores as nvarchar(max)
select @stores = STUFF( (select distinct N',' + QUOTENAME([STORE NAME])
                from src 
                FOR XML PATH(N'')), 1, 1, N'')

declare @sql as nvarchar(max) = 
N'select [Scancode], [Product Name],' + @stores +
N' from
(
    select * from src
) X
pivot
(
    SUM([Quantity])
    for [Store Name] IN (' + @stores + N')
) as p'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Also where is `N` defined?

Comment: I'm not sure about Sybase... I guess your tags confused me. `N` is for Unicode string literals.

Comment: @awashburn Do you want to me to remove my answer or is it still useful for you?